# JavaScript Canvas - avoiding subpixel grid lines

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

As a person who wrote lots of OpenGL code, I know the grid lines that can be seen when using texture atlases very well.

That being said, generally speaking, the rasterizer takes care of subpixel drawing.

Using the native 2D canvas context however, seems to be a whole other story.
While it supports a basic transformation API, I am finding it hard to actually use it.
I implemented a camera system much like OpenGL - translate to move, scale to zoom, and both operations are combined manually to zoom around a point.

The problems start to occur when the translation or scale are non-integer, as you'd have in any smooth camera.
The canvas will happily render anything subpixel, and introduce endless faulty grid lines all over the place.
Indeed, the only way to not have the whole canvas filled with grids, is to always translate in pixels, and scale with full numbers. This in turn means that scaling cannot be smooth in any way. It's less noticeable when objects are big, such that to get them smaller but still in the pixel boundary doesn't take much. It's very noticeable when objects are small, and you get periods of pressing the zoom button and it not doing anything, and then suddenly everything becomes smaller/bigger.

so tl;dr

- If a camera using translate/scale is smooth, subpixel rendering causes grid lines to go through the whole canvas.
- If a camera using translate/scale works only on pixel sizes, the smaller the logic-units (in this case tiles) are compared to the canvas size, the worse the camera will feel.

Is there an actual way to use the transform API? do I need WebGL to consistently render a simple tile map in JS?

Comment: After more searching, I saw someone mentioning that for images one can disable smoothing, however for the canvas primitives that depend on lines and such, it cannot be done, because of the SVG specs that force canvas drawing to be antialized. If this is true, I assume the only options left are using images for everything, or indeed using WebGL.